# Java constant classes chaining (dot notation)

Tags: java, class, chaining

If you have only ONE class with constants and then uses that class to get the constants, it is considered a bad idea. I read that usually constant classes are created relative to the closest class that are using these constants.

Then I will need to check for what I called the class before calling a constant, but can I have a syntax that calls different classes constants like this:

```
Data.MainMenu.STR_PLAY
Data.Shop.INT_PRICE_APPLE;
```

These classes will only hold values of primitive data types.

Where Data is the main class refering to Shop and MainMenu in some way? **This is the syntax I want to be able to do**.

Comment: Consider using enum as a type safe alternative to constants.  For example enum `MainMenu` with values such as `PLAY`, `STOP`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where Data is the main class refering to Shop and MainMenu in some way

That'd be an inner class

```
public class Data {
    public static class MainMenu {
        public static String STR_PLAY;
    } 
    // Same for Shop 
}
```

Comment: Isn't using interfaces with only constants considered bad? Now I'm confused.

Comment: @kev Bad according to what?

Comment: I recently read this article.https://medium.com/@Marlonlom/the-constant-interface-pattern-is-a-poor-use-of-interfaces-bad36f8f4d7c.

Comment: @cricket_007 but your solution to my question will work.

Comment: Well, I'm not using interfaces here anyway, so you'd have to ask Timothy